# jQuery: animate complete() event executes on stop()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-animate

Let's say I have this

```
$(".a").animate(
        {"left":"100%"},
        {duration:50000, complete:function(){
             $(".a").css("background-color","black");
        }}
);

$(".b").mouseover(function(){
        $(".a").stop();
});
```

When `.b` is `mouseover`-ed, `.a` will `stop()` and therefore its `complete:event` won't be triggered....

**What should I do so even if it stops its `complete:event` would be triggered?**

Is there any solution better than this?

```
function aaa(){
   $(".a").css("background-color","black");
 }    

$(".a").animate(
        {"left":"100%"},
        {duration:50000, complete:function(){
            aaa();
        }}
);

$(".b").mouseover(function(){
        $(".a").stop();
        aaa();
});
```

---

**[UPDATES]**
This is how my codes actually looks like, sorry didn't show it earlier...

```
$(".a").animate(
        {"left":"100%"},
        {duration:50000, complete:function(){
             alert("A");
        }}
);

$(".b").mouseover(function(){
        $(".a").stop().animate(
             {"top":"100%"}
        )
});
```

I want `alert("A")` to be executed only once.. but I don't stop users from `mouseover`-ing `.b` which stops `.a`..

If I was to write `.b`mouseover this way:

```
$(".b").mouseover(function(){
        $(".a").stop().animate(
             {"top":"100%"}
             {complete:function(){
                  alert("A");
             }}            
        )
});
```

it might `alert("A")` twice and I don't want that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `'jumpToEnd'` parameter of [jQuery.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

This will do the trick:

```
$(".a").stop(true,true);
```

[**DEMO:**](http://jsfiddle.net/JW872/)

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I've been looking for. I should have read more in jQuery API..

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be triggered, can't you just call the same function that is bound to the `complete:event` right after the `.stop()` call and get the same effect?

Comment: For some reason I only read half your question, and you had already suggested this. Not sure how I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've updated the question.. and the stop 'jumpToEnd' parameter is what I'm looking for. Problem solved :D